# Returning a Data Structure to Display information

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

I was reading [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/351784/285272) on SESE about encapsulation and getters/setters. Suppose I favor the use of immutable classes, so if a setter were implemented, it would return the a new object reflecting the change, for example:

```
//return a new Book reflecting the price change.
public Book updatePrice(double price){}
```

In the link, the answer suggested I have a method called `getDisplayinformation()` that returns a data structure.

> (think an array indexed by an enum, a struct, or a methodless class)

Following this advice how would I return a Book with a List of authors?

```
public final class Author{
    private final String id;
    private final String firstname;
    private final String lastname;
    //Constructor 
}
public final class Book{
    private String bookID;
    private final String title;
    private List<Author> authorsList;
    private double price;
    //Constructor
}
```

Suppose I wanted to return a `Map<String,String>`.

```
public Map<String,String> getDisplayinformation(){

    Map<String,String> displayMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    display.put("BookTitle", title);
    display.put("ID", bookID); 
    display.put("Price", price.toString())
    //insert authorsList;
    return displayMap;
}
```

Comment: Why not implement a toString method on the book class? I don't see the purpose of the map. But you can make a list a string, so I don't understand your problem

Comment: The answer on the SESE link I provided suggested a data structure to return fields I want display without breaking encapsulation. Given I want to display all the fields, I would have to provide a getter for everone. Isn't this bad design?

Comment: I agreed with the point made by @cricket_007.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you quote got half of it right. Providing getters for fields *does* break encapsulation, because it makes the caller dependent on some internal structure.

Now, returning a map where the caller needs to know the keys and knows what that information is, is basically not different than providing a getter for that field.

Object-orientation tries to tell us that the functionality needs to be bundled with the data. So, the `Book` has to have some method to present the `Book`. I would not call it `getDisplayInformation()`, rather simply `display()`. It can return something, and it can take relevant parameters too.

The point is, that anything returned by `display()` must be about the presentation, and must not be about the book. Semantics about being a book should be lost at that point, otherwise the caller will be tightly coupled.

So, it's ok to return an XML document, JSON document, HTML, a Wicket `Component`, whatever it is you can use for presentation that is independent of the `Book`.

Or, the method could take an argument to present itself *to*. Like AWT `Component.paint(Graphics g)` or something.

Note: this is actually a controversial subject. Mixed-paradigm development (a mix of procedural and ood) would argue that presentation needs to be separated from objects, while object-orientation argues that data and function belong always together.